# EXM Quick Test Error "Sitecore App Center password is not set" for SitecoreApps/Loader.aspx page

Tags: exm

We are getting below error in EXM when we were performing quick test during setup.

```
<a href='/sitecore/shell/applications/SitecoreApps/Loader.aspx' target='_blank'>Sitecore App Center</a> password is not set.
```

We are using local MTA.

```
<setting name="UseLocalMTA" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because EXM defaults to the Sitecore MTA if any of the following are true:

1. The license does not have the "Sitecore.AnyMTA" option.
2. The custom MTA is not configured.
3. EXM cannot connect to the custom MTA.

More details here: https://www.techguilds.com/blog/2018/02/the-sitecore-app-center-password-is-not-set

Answer (score 0):

We also had received this error during one of our setup. The main cause for this issue is that it uses EmailPreview / SpamCheck features which are not available without App Center.

If you are not using App Center, there is a workaround for the issue.

You can disable these features, so they won't cause this error to appear. To perform this action, just archive or remove the following items:

```
/sitecore/system/Modules/SPEAK/EmailCampaign/TaskPages/AdHockTaskPage/Review/EmailPreview
/sitecore/system/Modules/SPEAK/EmailCampaign/TaskPages/AdHockTaskPage/Review/SpamCheck
/sitecore/system/Modules/SPEAK/EmailCampaign/TaskPages/PeriodicalTaskPage/Review/EmailPreview
/sitecore/system/Modules/SPEAK/EmailCampaign/TaskPages/PeriodicalTaskPage/Review/SpamCheck
/sitecore/system/Modules/SPEAK/EmailCampaign/TaskPages/TrickleTaskPage/Review/EmailPreview
/sitecore/system/Modules/SPEAK/EmailCampaign/TaskPages/TrickleTaskPage/Review/SpamCheck
```